# adding missing seconds in a data frame in R or Python

Tags: python, r, dataframe, dataset, time-series

Assume I have data in the following format:

```
Time  Value
0.11  15
0.23  35
0.87  78
1.01  14
1.13  98
1.59  11
1.78  4
5.33  6
5.78  32
5.81  39
```

The time here is in seconds. Assume the frame rate is either 3 or 4 per second. In other words for every second there can be 3 or 4 rows. Yes **the given data set is irregular.**

Sometimes, there is a jump in the seconds like here (went from 1.78 to 5.33 - missing 2, 3, and 4 seconds).

Now **for every missing seconds I would like to add 3 rows** to have a final data like below:

```
Time  Value
0.11  15
0.23  35
0.87  78
1.01  14
1.13  98
1.59  11
1.78  4
2.01  NA
2.13  NA
2.59  NA
3.01  NA
3.13  NA
3.59  NA
4.01  NA
4.13  NA
4.59  NA
5.33  6
5.78  32
5.81  39
```

How would I do this in R or python some other programming language?

Assume it doesn't matter what the .01, .13, .59 (in final output) are... It can be .01, .02, .03. As long as there is 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 seconds and not 0, 1, 5 seconds

**UPDATE**: @r2evans solution works well when there is one time gap. How would I handle this for multiple time gaps as below:

```
Time  Value
0.11  15
0.23  35
0.87  78
1.01  14
1.13  98
1.59  11
1.78  4
5.33  6
5.78  32
5.81  39
6.01  14
6.13  98
6.59  11
7.78  4
7.33  6
7.81  39
12.78  4
12.33  6
12.81  39
```

Comment: It is not clear about the pattern in 'Time'.  If we look at the difference between adjacent elements, it is not the same

Comment: That is actually how the data is. The only thing we know is there are either 3 or 4 data points per second

Comment: Your intended result just seems totally random though - why .78, .13 and .59?

Comment: Assume it doesn't matter what the .78, .13, .59 are... It can be .01, .02, .03.

As long as there is 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 seconds and not 0, 1, 5

Comment: So if there can be "3 or 4 rows per second", how do we know whether to add 3 or 4 missing rows? I think we are all struggling to see how to go from the given data to the desired result.

Comment: Assume we just add 3 rows. I'm also struggling. I guess it doesn't have to be limited to an R solution... maybe python or something else?

The irregularity of the given data makes it hard...

Comment: Okay I noticed some issues with the original question. I have updated it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
txt <- "Time  Value
0.11  15
0.23  35
0.87  78
1.01  14
1.13  98
1.59  11
1.78  4
5.33  6
5.78  32
5.81  39"
dat <- read.table(text = txt, header = TRUE)
```

Some constants:

```
# largest "gap" possible, above which the gap will be "filled"
maxsplit <- 1 # sec
# when a gap is found, ensure times with this much gap are inserted
time_interval <- 1/3 # sec
```

Find the location(s) of all such gaps:

```
splits <- cumsum(diff(dat$Time) < maxsplit) # updated
split_inds <- which(duplicated(splits))     # updated
```

The `split_inds` is a vector of indices after which there is a gap of 1 second or more. For each of these gaps, we `seq`uence every `time_interval` seconds. It may not always be equally spaced, but it'll provide the coverage.

```
newtimes <- mapply(seq,
                   dat$Time[split_inds],
                   dat$Time[split_inds + 1],
                   MoreArgs = list(by = time_interval),
                   SIMPLIFY = FALSE)          # updated
newtimes <- unlist(lapply(newtimes, `[`, -1)) # updated
newtimes
# [1] 2.113333 2.446667 2.780000 3.113333 3.446667 3.780000
# [7] 4.113333 4.446667 4.780000 5.113333
```

From that, we will need to remove the first row, since that exists verbatim in the original data. (Note that if the gap is a perfect multiple of `time_interval`, the last row may also be a repeat ... other filters can be used, perhaps looking for `duplicated(dat$Time)`, perhaps hard-coding a check for near-equality. **Edit**: my first version of this answer always removed the last row as well, which could allow a gap of just-under `2*time_interval`.)

```
newdat <- rbind(dat, 
                data.frame(Time = newtimes, Value = NA)) # updated
```

I'm assuming that ordering by `$Time` is desired ...

```
newdat <- newdat[order(newdat$Time),]
```

The resulting data.

```
newdat
#        Time Value
# 1  0.110000    15
# 2  0.230000    35
# 3  0.870000    78
# 4  1.010000    14
# 5  1.130000    98
# 6  1.590000    11
# 7  1.780000     4
# 11 2.113333    NA
# 12 2.446667    NA
# 13 2.780000    NA
# 14 3.113333    NA
# 15 3.446667    NA
# 16 3.780000    NA
# 17 4.113333    NA
# 18 4.446667    NA
# 19 4.780000    NA
# 20 5.113333    NA
# 8  5.330000     6
# 9  5.780000    32
# 10 5.810000    39
```

**Update**:

There was one bug in the code, fixed above (and annotated). There is an assumption, though, that `$Time` is ordered; if this is not assured, it should be done before the code above:

```
dat <- dat[ order(dat$Time), ]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This works if there is only one gap in the dataset. How would I handle multiple gaps? I updated the original question with a sample dataset with multiple gaps. Your current solution gives this error
`Error in seq.default(dots[[1L]][[3L]], dots[[2L]][[3L]], by = 0.333333333333333) : 
  wrong sign in 'by' argument`

Comment: Okay. I added that however, there is another issue with multiple gaps: 
`Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : 
  names do not match previous names`

PS: Really appreciate your help

Comment: When I use your new data and the code above (one more minor and unrelated change in the `rbind` call, btw), it works without error or warning. I *can*, however, reproduce that error by using different column names; make sure you correctly spell `Time` and `Value` (case-sensitive) or change *all* references to them to your actual column headers.

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure someone will come up with a more elegant solution, but this should work:

```
Time  <- c(0.11, 0.23, 0.87, 1.01, 1.13, 1.59, 1.78, 5.33, 5.78, 5.81)
Value <- c(15, 35, 78, 14, 98, 11, 4, 6, 32, 39)

v1 <- data.frame(Time, Value, rounded=floor(Time))
v <- v1

for (i in min(v1$rounded):max(v1$rounded)) {

    while (length(which(v1$rounded == i)) < 3) {

        nextTimeVal <- max(v1$Time[v1$rounded == i])
        if (!is.finite(nextTimeVal)) {
            nextTimeVal <- i + 0.001
        } else {
            nextTimeVal <- nextTimeVal + 0.001
        }

        v1 <- rbind(v1, c(nextTimeVal, NA, i))
    }
    cat(i, '\n')

}

v1 <- v1[order(v1$Time), ]

print(v)
print(v1)
```

Comment: Yep, r2evans beat me to it.